# Add blank row programatically in XrTable (XtraReport)?

Tags: winforms, devexpress, xtrareport

I have 6 records of data and want to add 4 blank rows more to make a list of 10 rows in the run-time. What must I do?

Comment: what dummy data you will insert.. does it make report odd to see the results??

Comment: My customer request that, I don't know what does it for, he want to display 16 records per gapge, but if we have 20 records, that will be 16 row (with data) in first page, 4 rows(with data) and 12 rows (blank) in the second page. Exactly, 16 rows per page :3

Comment: have you limited no of records per page on report?? what will you put in the extra rows?? 0 for every data.. if there is any primary key then?

Comment: I limited no of record per page, 16. But my customer want: if a page have less than 16 record, filling the rest with blank row, example: 21 records, the second page will have 5 records and 11 BLANK rows, mean CELLS only with blank text

Answer (score 0):

For data source modification procedure in the `BeforePrint` event.. Refer to the sample code snippet:

```
void report1_BeforePrint(object sender, System.Drawing.Printing.PrintEventArgs e) {
            DataDataSet ds = new DataDataSet();
            this.sitE_SummaryTableAdapter1.Fill(ds.SITE_Summary);
            foreach (DataDataSet.SITE_SummaryRow row in ds.SITE_Summary) {
                double val = Convert.ToDouble(row["SITE_Summary.Heating_Energy_Transfer"]);
                row["SITE_Summary.Heating_Energy_Transfer"] = convertTemperature(val, true);
            }
            this.report1.DataSource = ds;
        }
```

Comment: The code seem like the manual binding code, how about the programatically row adding? Ex: xrTable1.Rows.Add(new Row())

Comment: Tell me the way which you used to limit the number of records. if you have used some express then that will based on the binding... Adding rows to xrTable will not make report to determine that there is 20 rows if your restriction based on the records in the data source..

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the issue by create extra "Get" properties

Comment: Great.. Then update your question with answer or put solution in answer and  accept it..